# Unable to connect to mongodb - mlab

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I am trying to connect to mlab database using the command

mongo ds159978.mlab.com:59978/dbname -u dbuser -p dbpassword

but it is giving connection error. I am using the database username and password only not the username and password of account.

Then I tried using

nc -w 3 -v ds159978.mlab.com 59978

but again there is error

nc: connect to ds159978.mlab.com port 59978 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

What could possibly be the reason behind this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried using the --authenticationDatabase flag? maybe your credentials are not stored in "dbname". at the end of your command try adding --authenticationDatabase admin

Comment: not working - again the same error

Comment: Ahh so I overlooked the second part of the question. I'm not too familiar with what mlab gives you. But do they give you access to the server that the mongod is running on? and if so?can you log on to that server and are you successfully able to open a mongo connection via a mongo shell?

Comment: Actually , I think that the problem is that I am working behind a proxy server. Is there any way to bypass proxy server to connect to mlab.com